# How to save image file created from python code to a folder in the same virtual environment as the python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm using a selenium package called Selenium-Screenshot to take a full image screenshot of a webpage and then save the corresponding image in a empty folder that is currently in the same (.venv) as the python file.

I'm having trouble inputting how to reference that file in the function below,
(specifically the parameter: save_path= r'.'). The function is based off of the python package PIL (pillow).

```
img_url = ob.full_screenshot(driver, save_path= r'.', image_name = 'image.png', is_load_at_runtime=True,
                                          load_wait_time=3)
```

Here is the relevant error I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Folder_1\\image.png'
```

Here is my full code:

```
import os
from Screenshot import Screenshot
from selenium import webdriver

ob = Screenshot.Screenshot()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.google.com"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()


img_url = ob.full_screenshot(driver, save_path= r'.', image_name = 'image.png', is_load_at_runtime=True,
                                          load_wait_time=3)

driver.close()

driver.quit()
```

I tried using os.makedir, but that has failed. I've also tried save_path = r'\folder_name' or r'D:/Folder_1', which also failed.

I want to be able to implement this code as package on any other users computer.
If there is a better way, (such as creating a new folder and saving the image, etc.), please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path names are preferred over relative ones unless the working directory was intentionally set.

In a virtual environment (venv) located at `VENV` directory, the Python executable is inside `/VENV/bin` and for the images another subdirectory should be created, e.g. `/VENV/images`. (I'm used to the Unix directory separators)

Here is how to get the VENV:

```
import sys

venvdir = sys.prefix
if venvdir == sys.base_prefix:
    raise RuntimeError("Not running in a venv")

# now use venvdir to construct the absolute path of your image directory
# and then use that as a base for image files
# -- or --
# chdir to the image directory
```